# Table is not physically exists but query from that table returns data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a reporting script that dump sales data,
[image]
B
Even though this query returns data such table doesn't exists. 
[image]

Is there way of creating hidden temporary data?

Can anyone guess what is this?

Thx/G

Comment: what its return ?? can you dump it ?

Comment: My guess is that it's an ureadable image.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that this table doesn't exist in the database that you're querying against? Are you implementing any form of result caching that hasn't been cleared since the table was dropped?

Comment: Check your database connection parameters for database name. May be it is connecting to a different database than what you are thinking.

Comment: [Occam's razor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam's_razor) applies here.  Your code is very likely connecting to a different database than you expect, or the table does exist. Either way, use a regular MySQL client to verify that outside of your code with `SHOW TABLES FROM <databasename>` and check this application's configuration.

Comment: Are you having **SLAVE** and **MASTER** db ??

Comment: @MarkBaker : yes mark see the screen attached.

Comment: What we can't see from those images is whether it really is the same database accessed via phpmyadmin and via your code.... but one query is against table `sales_items_temp` (shown in your code) the other against table `ospos_sales_items_temp` (shown in your phpmyadmin image)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski : here the table list http://screencloud.net/v/k6yK

Comment: @MarkBaker : ospos_ is table prefix so we can leave that

Comment: That's inserted automatically by your call to `$this->db->from()` is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a temporary table. Temporary tables have a life span within the current session. Once the session is closed, the table is gone (so even if you log into the same database, you will not see it). Perhaps somewhere before that fragment there is a piece of code that creates it?